# Regarding installing meteor js

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor js. I just wanted to try some samples.
But I am not able to install.

While installing using

```
curl -x http_proxy https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

I am getting the following exception

---

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time 
>   Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 102  3586    0  3586    0     0    741      0 --:--:--  0:00:04
>   --:--:--   936 Downloading Meteor distribution curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
>
> gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file tar: Child returned status 1 tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now Installation failed.

---

Tried other way of installing using git. I downloaded using `git clone` and run the `./meteor --help`. For that also I have got

---

It's the first time you've run Meteor from a git checkout.
I will download a kit containing all of Meteor's dependencies.

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now Failed to install dependency kit.
```

---

Kindly help me how to install. Correct me if I am missing anything for the installation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the URL is broken?

```
curl -x http://https://install.meteor.com
```

The command from [the meteor examples page](http://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard) is:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | sh
```

What OS are you running?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried in Linux OS. As my network is proxy enabled I have given the proxy host like "curl -x http://<http://proxy>uname:password@proxy_host:proxy_port  https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh". While posting it has been removed.

Comment: if you don't have node js installed sometimes it give some error while installing meteor specially in Windows...